# Help with Crash in Dual-Booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10

I would definitely appreciate anyone's help in my Windows 10 and Ubuntu dual-booting pursuit.

At first, I was unable to boot up Ubuntu from the USB drive. The option to boot from a USB drive was not given until I disabled secure boot. After overcoming that hurdle, there was another immediate one: after selecting to boot from the USB Storage Device, my computer would then take me to the Ubuntu Installer boot, but it would freeze on that menu, and after a few seconds, it would then take me to a screen that displayed some odd code, which is seen in the photo I provided. On that last screen, I would always hit a brick wall that thwarted my progress: my computer would remain frozen, and I would have to resort to powering off my computer and turning it back on to Windows.

The entirety of my attempts last night yielded the same results. For some reason, though, when I attempted the process again this morning, it did not freeze on the Ubuntu menu, but when I selected the first option, which I believe is to try Ubuntu, I again was brought to the same screen.

By the way, my laptop is a Dell Inspiron 17 7000 series. It has a i7 processor, 8gb of RAM, 1TB hard drive, and an Nvidia GTX 960M graphics card. I just got it a few days ago. And I've tried with both Ubuntu 15.10 and 14.04.3.

Any help and direction in this matter would totally be appreciated.

Thanks.

[Brick Wall Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxPnP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Using intel_pstate instead of acpi-cpufreq to manage cpu frequency seems to prevent kernel panics on the **Inspiron 3551** due to a regression in step_wise.c in the default Ubuntu kernel. This is a guide on how to switch to the intel_pstate driver. **You have to do this from the Live-CD** [Instructions on how to use Ubuntu Live CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD)

Install cpupower:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-common linux-tools-generic && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Edit /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=enable"

sudo update-grub
```

**Reboot** and check if the intel_pstate driver is enabled:

cpupower frequency-info

***intel_pstate has two frequency governors: performance and powersave, but not ondemand. Switch between the two with:**

```
sudo cpupower frequency-set -g powersave

sudo cpupower frequency-set -g performance
```

[More information is available for reading here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD)

Answer (score 0):

When you see

[image: this]

press any key to see

[image: this]

, then press the escape key to see

[image: this]

, then press f6 to see

[image: this]

, then the escape key and type

```
intel_pstate=enable
```

at the end and press enter.  This should allow you to boot from the LiveCD (or USB).

Comment: You probably do not want above BIOS boot screens but want UEFI boot with gives you grub menu. And then you have to manually edit grub to add same boot parameters. At grub menu you can use e for edit, scroll to linux line and replace quiet splash with nomodeset.
How to set NOMODESET and other kernel boot options in grub2 - both BIOS liveCD & grub first boot ( also UEFI with grub) 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132